# sympy simplify function contained a bug in sign

Tags: python, sympy, bug-reporting

I was using the sympy to verify some hand calculation, the version was anaconda and

```
import sympy as sp
sp.__version__
'1.11.1'
```

on Windows 11 Jupyter notebook.

The code ran as follow

```
from sympy import Function
eta = Function('eta')
from sympy import *
s,c,h=symbols('s c h',real=True)

A,B =symbols("A B")
q=exp(-2*pi*exp(s))
chi_0=eta(s)**(-1) * q**(0-(c-1)/24)*(1-q)
```

The following code

```
print( chi_0.diff(s).subs((eta(s)**(-1)).diff(s),-B) .subs(eta(s)**(-1),A) .subs(s,0) )
```

produced the correct results

```
print( chi_0.diff(s).subs((eta(s)**(-1)).diff(s),-B) .subs(eta(s)**(-1),A) .subs(s,0) )

-2*pi*A*(1/24 - c/24)*(1 - exp(-2*pi))*exp(-2*pi*(1/24 - c/24)) + 2*pi*A*exp(-2*pi)*exp(-2*pi*(1/24 - c/24)) - B*(1 - exp(-2*pi))*exp(-2*pi*(1/24 - c/24))
```

Notice the sign in the term `-2*pi*A*(1/24 - c/24)*(1 - exp(-2*pi))*exp(-2*pi*(1/24 - c/24))`. However, when I tried to cancel the `*exp(-2*pi*(1/24 - c/24))`,

```
#bug
print( (( chi_0.diff(s).subs((eta(s)**(-1)).diff(s),-B) .subs(eta(s)**(-1),A) .subs(s,0) )/exp(pi*(c-1)/12)  ).simplify()  )
(-pi*A*(1 - exp(2*pi))*(c - 1)/12 + 2*pi*A + B*(1 - exp(2*pi)))*exp(-2*pi)
```

Notice that two of the terms `(-pi*A*(1 - exp(2*pi))*(c - 1)/12`  and `B*(1 - exp(2*pi)))*exp(-2*pi)` obtained the wrong sign, while the sign of the  `2*pi*A` remained correct.

Though an expansion statement could fix the result,

```
print( (( chi_0.diff(s).subs((eta(s)**(-1)).diff(s),-B) .subs(eta(s)**(-1),A) .subs(s,0) ).expand()/exp(pi*(c-1)/12)  ).simplify() )
-pi*A*c*exp(-2*pi)/12 + pi*A*c/12 - pi*A/12 + 25*pi*A*exp(-2*pi)/12 - B + B*exp(-2*pi)
```

it was not useful.

How did this happen?

Comment: There is no bug. All the signs are correct but you have to account for the signs of all factors in a term (hence why the signs are correct after expanding).

Comment: @OscarBenjamin That's not what happened. The relative sign between three additive terms changed as shown above, the ` 2*pi*A*exp(-2*pi)*exp(-2*pi*(1/24 - c/24))` had the same sign, but the sign of the other terms changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the behavior with a simpler example:

```
>>> from sympy.abc import x, y, z
>>> from sympy import signsimp
>>> a = (1-x)*(y-1)*(1-z)/-1; a
-(1 - x)*(1 - z)*(y - 1)
>>> b = signsimp(_); b  # make expression canonical wrt sign
-(x - 1)*(y - 1)*(z - 1)
```

You can see that two things happened: order of factors was changed (but that's ok with commutative factors) and the signs of *two* factors was changed (and that preserves the overall sign).

If you have doubts about whether two exprssions are equal or not you can try the following (which will return None if it can't tell):

```
>>> a.equals(b)
True
```

`signsimp` is part of the simplification process and might be one of the reasons that signs within factors changed (in a mathematically valid way).

Comment: res1=(( chi_0.diff(s).subs((eta(s)**(-1)).diff(s),-B) .subs(eta(s)**(-1),A) .subs(s,0) )/exp(pi*(c-1)/12)  ).simplify()
res2=(( chi_0.diff(s).subs((eta(s)**(-1)).diff(s),-B) .subs(eta(s)**(-1),A) .subs(s,0) ).expand()/exp(pi*(c-1)/12)  ).simplify() , then 
res1==res2 returned "False". The singsimp seemed misbehaved.

Comment: `==` tests for structural equality. `equals` returns True for mathematical equality. If you look at res1 and res2 you will see that res1 has all terms over a denominator whereas res2 is the expanded form: `(res1.expand() == res2) == res1.equals(res2) == True`